# How to query specific values from a two level Mongoose populate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I would like to query specific values from a two level Mongoose populate.

```
 const {_id, name, email, role, account, subUsers } = await User.findById(req.user.id)
    .populate({
        path    : 'account',     // need specific values from this accountModel (_id & name)
        populate: [
            { path: 'providers' }, // need specific values from this model (_id & name) 
        ]
    })
    .populate('subUsers', {_id: 1, name: 1});
```

Comment: What problem are you having with this task?

Comment: I got this solved; Thank you for your attention to this.

Comment: Lovely. If you can edit the question to explain what issue you were having (or edit the answer to say why that was the solution) that may help future readers. Thank you for adding a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
const {_id, name, email, role, account, subUsers } = await User.findById(req.user.id)
  .populate([ 
    { path: 'account', select: '_id name', populate: [ { path: 'providers', select: '_id name' } ] },
    { path: 'subUsers', select: '_id name' }
  ])
```